# LLDB differs from Xcode debugger UI (possible bug?)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, debugging, lldb

The Xcode Debugger UI shows a variable (`wordList`) as nil, but when I use `po` to print that variable I get the content ( so in effect it's not nil). An `NSLog()` also shows the content of the `wordList` variable. It seems that the UI is effectively wrong. Could this be a bug on Xcode?

I'm including a screenshot to make my question clearer:[image: debugger screenshot]

Comment: "Could this be a bug on Xcode?" -- It has happened once or twice...

Answer (score 0):

There have been such bugs.  If you are seeing this in the most recent Xcode (5.0.2) then it is a bug that was supposed to be fixed, in which case file it with bugreporter.apple.com.